# PlayHaven Android integration

Tags: android, playhaven

I'm trying to implement PlayHaven's SDK in my Android application and while I do get Interstital ads, I cannot seem to capture the event of content dismissed.
I do get a log when the content is loaded.

This is what I've tried:

```
PlayHaven.configure(this, R.string.token, R.string.secret);
                OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest();
                open.send(this);

                placement = new Placement("some_placement");
                placement.setListener(pl); //PlacementListener
                placement.preload(this);
```

The PlacementListener(pl) implementation:

```
private PlacementListener pl = new PlacementListener() {

        @Override
        public void contentLoaded(Placement placement) {
            Log.i(TAG_PH, "PlayHaven contentLoaded");//this log is displayed
            startActivity(FullScreen.createIntent(Splash.this,placement));
        }

        @Override
        public void contentFailed(Placement placement, PlayHavenException e) {
            Log.i(TAG_PH, "PlayHaven contentFailed");
        }

        @Override
        public void contentDismissed(Placement placement, DismissType dismissType,
                Bundle data) {
            Log.i(TAG_PH, "PlayHaven content Dismissed");//this log is **NOT** displayed
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onActivityResult method, you can use the following code:

```
String placementTag = data.getStringExtra(PlayHavenView.BUNDLE_PLACEMENT_TAG);
PlayHavenView.DismissType dismissType = (PlayHavenView.DismissType) data.getSerializableExtra(PlayHavenView.BUNDLE_DISMISS_TYPE);
```

You will get back dismissType. The values you are looking for are EmergencyClose (triggered when a user clicks on the X button to close a content unit), NoThanks (user declines the content unit offer), SelfClose (the Content Unit dismisses itself which happens when the SDK has to intelligently close a content unit), and BackButton (when the user presses back).